# using grep to parse output from another command

Tags: unix, grep

after doing the command in the terminal: `forever list`

i get the following output:

```
info:   Forever processes running
data:       uid  command script           forever pid logfile                              uptime        
data:   [0] 0ClV node    enfomo-server.js 376     377 /Users/USERNAME/.forever/0ClV.log 0:0:37:26.987
```

i need to use grep or some alternative to give as output the following string only:

```
/Users/USERNAME/.forever/0ClV.log
```

what is the proper command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with grep using the `-o` flag which only prints the matching part:

```
forever list | grep -o '\/Users.*log'
```

Comment: Note: this approach relies on the content, rather than the position.  This may be ideal, or it may be limited, depending on the data, which is not characterized.

Comment: Thank you Paul for pointing this out, I interpreted the question as being dependent on content.

Comment: ahh. was a character or two off in my regex.

Answer (score 2):

First you might want to isolate only the lines you want with grep, then awk would work:

```
grep node file | awk '{print $7}'
```

or cut:

```
grep node file | cut -d\  -f7
```